# Batch: parameter with both expansion symbols

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file

**Question:**

Is it possible to have a function receive a parameter which has both a percent sign and an exclamation mark?

**Problem:**

I am in a `FOR /D` processing directories in this fashion:

```
FOR /D %%d IN ("%~1\*") DO (
    CALL :process "%%~fd"
)
```

The problem comes when the subdirectory name (`%%~fd`) contains both a `%` and a `!` (which is completely legal in *Windows*), such as `C:\&!x#%`. When I read `%1` in the subprocedure `:process`, the percent sign disappears. If I *EnableDelayedExpansion*, then the exclamation mark does.

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts) and, apparently, this cannot be solved. If delayed expansion is disabled, the `%` will be erased. If delayed expansion is enabled, the `!` will be.

**Example:**

*ex.bat:*

```
@ECHO OFF
SET arg="%~1"
CALL :clean_echo %arg%
GOTO :EOF

:clean_echo
SET arg="%~1"
SET arg=%arg:&=^&%
SET arg=%arg:|=^|%
SET arg=%arg:<=^<%
SET arg=%arg:>=^>%
ECHO %arg:~1,-1%
GOTO :EOF
```

If I execute `ex.bat "%!"` the output is just `!`. The `%` is lost when it is passed on to the `:clean_echo` subprocedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be done, you need to double the percents and prefix the exclamation marks with a caret.
But then it fails with single carets in the name and that can't be solved in a proper way.

As Magoo said, it's always better to use a variable and only transfer the variable name instead of the content.

But in the function you should use delayed expansion to expand the variable.

```
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

FOR /D %%d IN ("%~1\*") DO (
    set "var=%%~fd"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    CALL :process var
    endlocal
)
exit /b

:process
set "content=!%1!"
echo !content!
exit /B
```

Comment: "It's always better to use a variable and only transfer the variable name instead of the content"
Great piece of advice, thanks @jeb and @Magoo!

Answer (score 3):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /d %%a IN (*) DO (ECHO %%~fa
 SET "var=%%~fa"
 CALL :proc var
)

GOTO :EOF

:proc
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%x IN ('set %1 2^>nul') DO IF /i "%1"=="%%x" (
 ECHO %%y
)
GOTO :eof
```

You don't say enough about your application, but essentially passing such strings as a parameter is doomed to fail. Here's a method that may work for you, although it won't cope with the data starting with `=` (I've seen filenames containing `=`.)

It's a game of piggy-in-the-middle with the parser being piggy. So long as your data remains assigned to a metavariable it seems fine. Really depends on the unstated - precisely what you want to do with it.